# 400 bad request in graph API but same working in postman

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am trying to hit a Get method - `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me`

but I am getting

> 400 bad request.

But the same API is working in Postman, with token

I am getting 400 bad request. But the same API is working in Postman, with token

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The ***"400 Bad Request"*** error usually occurs if the query you are passing is incorrect or not valid.

For sample:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
```

[image]

**To resolve the error**, execute the query like below with no specified body or headers:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
```

[image]

In the Access Token blade copy the access token and decode it like below:

[image]

Make sure that the access token as **scp** has **`User.Read`** API permission.

***If still the issue persists*, check the below:**

- Install the Fiddler App and check the trace:

[image]

You can make use of below sample code:

```
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(requestAdapter);

var result = await graphClient.Me.GetAsync();
```

**Reference:**

[Get a user - Microsoft Graph v1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp)

Comment: But same code working in postman and other application

Comment: Could you paste the screenshot of the error.